# psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "NULL"

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I'm trying to upload a CSV file using the copy from command and the Python psycopg2 library. I understand that the error stems from trying to insert a char value into a double precision column, but I specified null values as `"NULL"` when creating my csv file and in the Postgres copy command I also specified nulls as `"NULL"`, so I'm not sure why it isn't converting those values when uploading.

**Creating the csv file:**

```
with file_path.open(mode='w', newline='') as outfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=delimiter, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

    if include_headers:
        csv_writer.writerow(col[0] for col in self.cursor.description)
    for row in self.cursor:
        csv_writer.writerow(['NULL' if value is None else value for value in row])
```

**Uploading the file to postgres:**

```
sql = """COPY {table} FROM STDIN WITH (DELIMITER '{sep}', NULL 'NULL', FORMAT CSV, HEADER True);""".format(table=table, sep=sep)

with open(file) as f:
    self.cursor.copy_expert(sql=sql, file=f, size=size)
self.commit()
```

**Error:**

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for type double precision:
"NULL" CONTEXT:  COPY test_table, line 25, column Lat:
"NULL"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `QUOTE_MINIMAL`, otherwise your `None`s will show up as `"NULL"` (including the quotes) in the file, which is why they are not recognized properly by `COPY`.

But I think you don't have to go through all this as `COPY` is able to deal with CSV files just fine. Open the file and use the `copy_from` and `copy_to` methods.

Comment: Do you know of a better way to create csv files from sql queries? It seems inefficient to have to iterate over all of the values to convert nulls so it can work with the copy command.

Comment: Yes, you can di that much simpler, see my extended answer.